# Good book for functional analysis with detail explaination?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Can anyone recommend me a good book for functional analysis with clear and concise explanations and examples? Thanks

Comment: key word (or name) is Erwin Kreyzsig

Comment: Related: [An application-heavy functional analysis textbook?](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/an-application-heavy-functional-analysis-textbook)

Comment: The answer depends on what you already know. Are you familiar with some measure theory, for instance?

Comment: I have no backround of measure theory, just a basic knowledge of L spaces

Answer (score 2):

Try Erwin Kreyzsig's **Introductory functional analysis with applications** which is excellent in the basics.

Comment: This is one of the best math books ever written. It is so clear you can almost read it in your bed with little pencil and paper!